# anaconda3 not properly installed

Tags: python, anaconda3

I downed a version of anaconda3 from the official website:
Anaconda3-2020.11-Windows-x86.exe
for windows7 32 bit.

After installation, the guide indicates it's successfully installed on path C:\Users\Administrator\anaconda3

But I didn't find an icon in the windows start menu, and I could not find an appropriate exe file to start in the installment path folder. There're only:

```
folers: conda-meta, Lib, pkgs
exes: _conda.exe, Uninstall_Anaconda3.exe
other: .nonadmin
```

I assumed there should be an exe file to start anaconda3 as I have done before. What's wrong ? and how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you have added path then, in cmd or powershell type,

`conda activate base`

If it fails,

From your start menu, you should find Anaconda navigator. Launch from there.

Comment: I entered my installation path C:\Users\Administrator\anaconda3, typed in cmd "conda activate base", and get a return as 'unacceptable character #x0000': special characters are not allowed'. Then instead, I typed "_conda activate base", and returned 'important: You may need to close and restart your shell after running 'conda init'", I still didn't see anything in my windows start menu.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, same folders, same files, Anaconda installed with success but without asking the administrator verification (don't know why). Running the installation .exe file as administrator completed the installation exactly as expected.